# How to select the exchange values in different days?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I'm using ClickHouse, I want to know which of this "search word" has been distinct path values in different days

My data

```
    date    searchword  path
1   2019-10-02  word1   url-1
2   2019-10-03  word1   url-2
3   2019-10-04  word1   url-1
4   2019-10-11  word1   url-1
5   2019-10-07  word2   url-4
6   2019-10-08  word3   url-5
7   2019-10-09  word3   url-5
8   2019-10-10  word3   url-5
9   2019-10-08  word4   url-5
10  2019-10-09  word4   url-5
11  2019-10-10  word4   url-5
12  2019-10-10  word4   url-6
13  2019-10-11  word4   url-5
14  2019-10-10  word5   url-7
15  2019-10-09  word5   url-8
16  2019-10-11  word5   url-7
```

Desired result

```
word1 
word5
```

But not *word4* because there aren't an exchange of values, but two values for the same day

*word1* (two paths, one each day, value of row 2 is url2 and other days, rows 1 and 3 value is url1 )

*word5* (multiple values, rows 14 with value url-7 and row 15 url-8).

I think I should use sequenceMatch or windowFunnel function, any idea?

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```sql
SELECT searchword
FROM (
  /* intermediate result of SELECT below
  ┌─searchword─┬─date_paths_array──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬─isExchanged─┐
  │ word3      │ [('2019-10-09',['url-5']),('2019-10-10',['url-5']),('2019-10-08',['url-5'])]                                  │           0 │
  │ word5      │ [('2019-10-10',['url-7']),('2019-10-11',['url-7']),('2019-10-09',['url-8'])]                                  │           1 │
  │ word1      │ [('2019-10-04',['url-1']),('2019-10-02',['url-1']),('2019-10-03',['url-2']),('2019-10-11',['url-1'])]         │           1 │
  │ word4      │ [('2019-10-08',['url-5']),('2019-10-10',['url-5','url-6']),('2019-10-09',['url-5']),('2019-10-11',['url-5'])] │           0 │
  └────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────┘
  */
  SELECT 
    searchword, 
    groupArray(date_paths) date_paths_array, 
    arrayFirstIndex((x, index) -> 
        index != length(date_paths_array) 
        AND hasAny(x.2, date_paths_array[index + 1].2) = 0, 
      date_paths_array, 
      arrayEnumerate(date_paths_array)) > 0 isExchanged
  FROM (    
    /* intermediate result of SELECT below
    ┌─searchword─┬─date_paths───────────────────────┐
    │ word1      │ ('2019-10-04',['url-1'])         │
    │ word3      │ ('2019-10-09',['url-5'])         │
    │ word5      │ ('2019-10-10',['url-7'])         │
    │ word1      │ ('2019-10-02',['url-1'])         │
    │ word4      │ ('2019-10-08',['url-5'])         │
    │ word2      │ ('2019-10-07',['url-4'])         │
    │ word5      │ ('2019-10-11',['url-7'])         │
    │ word5      │ ('2019-10-09',['url-8'])         │
    │ word3      │ ('2019-10-10',['url-5'])         │
    │ word1      │ ('2019-10-03',['url-2'])         │
    │ word3      │ ('2019-10-08',['url-5'])         │
    │ word1      │ ('2019-10-11',['url-1'])         │
    │ word4      │ ('2019-10-10',['url-5','url-6']) │
    │ word4      │ ('2019-10-09',['url-5'])         │
    │ word4      │ ('2019-10-11',['url-5'])         │
    └────────────┴──────────────────────────────────┘
    */
    SELECT searchword, (date, groupArray(path)) date_paths
    FROM (
      /* test dataset */    
      SELECT d.1 order_num, toDate(d.2) date, d.3 searchword, d.4 path
      FROM (  
        SELECT arrayJoin([
          (1, '2019-10-02', 'word1', 'url-1'),
          (2, '2019-10-03', 'word1', 'url-2'),
          (3, '2019-10-04', 'word1', 'url-1'),
          (4, '2019-10-11', 'word1', 'url-1'),
          (5, '2019-10-07', 'word2', 'url-4'),
          (6, '2019-10-08', 'word3', 'url-5'),
          (7, '2019-10-09', 'word3', 'url-5'),
          (8, '2019-10-10', 'word3', 'url-5'),
          (9, '2019-10-08', 'word4', 'url-5'),
          (10, '2019-10-09', 'word4', 'url-5'),
          (11, '2019-10-10', 'word4', 'url-5'),
          (12, '2019-10-10', 'word4', 'url-6'),
          (13, '2019-10-11', 'word4', 'url-5'),
          (14, '2019-10-10', 'word5', 'url-7'),
          (15, '2019-10-09', 'word5', 'url-8'),
          (16, '2019-10-11', 'word5', 'url-7')]) d))
    WHERE date >= '2019-10-01' AND date < '2019-11-01'      
    GROUP BY searchword, date)
  GROUP BY searchword  
  HAVING count() > 1)
WHERE isExchanged;
/* Result:
┌─searchword─┐
│ word5      │
│ word1      │
└────────────┘
*/
```